# Flutter Stepper last step does not fully scroll in

Tags: flutter, dart

I use a stepper with 8 steps for a user registration flow. The last step is a summary with all data the user entered. Now when I run this, the summary step does not fully scroll down to the very end showing all fields, the user has to manually scroll in the whole step, although it fits easily on a screen.

Is there a way to tell a stepper to show the whole content of a step on the screen?

Edit: Screenshot attached
[image]

Comment: Mind to show a screenshot of what you are describing? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks yeah, added a screenshot. So with every step I go forward, the screen content goes a little more down each time instead of all content of each step is always centered on the screen.

Comment: Well, that's just the way the Stepper works. It goes down each step on vertical Stepper, but you should be able to tweak it to your needs. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve that the contents of each step is always shown as soon as the user taps the "next" button or taps the headline. Kind of "scroll up if next button is tapped"

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a hook in "next" button in each step to have a delayed scroll, looks very nice and smooth-ish.

```
buttonNext() {
  ...
  delayedScroll();
}

void delayedScroll() async {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
      _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeOut);
    });
}
```

Comment: where do you add the _scrollController? to which widget, I thought Stepper doesnt have controller property.